# Haskell program: How to read files recursively and search their contents?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm struggling to write a Haskell program which would cover at least these:

1. Search through a given directory (recursively) for files containing a specified string
2. Execution can be parameterized through command-line (typing `--name SomeName` will throw every file containing `SomeName`)
3. Can be run both Unix and Windows

Considering above, how should reading files and searching functions should be written? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you, like, tried anything yourself yet? We aren't just going to give you teh codez that does all of that...

Comment: I wouldn't count on that. But maybe someone found out a good tutorial or anything that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`System.Directory`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.2.1/docs/System-Directory.html).

To fetch the entries of a directory:

```
getDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
```

To check if an entry is a non-directory:

```
doesFileExist :: FilePath -> IO Bool
```

To check if an entry is a directory:

```
doesDirectoryExist :: FilePath -> IO Bool
```